# Get total number of input tags in a div element

Tags: javascript, html

new to js and trying to get a total number of input tags in a div element then display the total.

Thanks for the help and sorry if this is a repeat question.

```
<div class="card-body">

  <span>0</span> / <span id="total-inputs"></span>
  
  <ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input-1" class="sum" value="1" >
        <label for="input-1">
          Input 1
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input-2" class="sum" value="1" >
        <label for="input-2">
          Input 2
        </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("card-body");
const nodes = element.getElementsByTagName("input");
document.getElementById("total-inputs").innerHTML = nodes.length;
```

Getting this error:

> TypeError: element.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const element = document.getElementsByClassName("card-body")` should be `const element = document.getElementsByClassName("card-body")[0]` since `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array:

```js
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("card-body")[0];
const nodes = element.getElementsByTagName("input");
document.getElementById("total-inputs").innerHTML = nodes.length;
```

```html
<div class="card-body">

  <span>0</span> / <span id="total-inputs"></span>
  
  <ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input-1" class="sum" value="1" >
        <label for="input-1">
          Input 1
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input-2" class="sum" value="1" >
        <label for="input-2">
          Input 2
        </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I did not know that getElementsByClassName() returned an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new function `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`.

Example:

```
var div = document.querySelector('div.card-body');
var inputs = div.querySelectorAll('input');
var inputLenth = inputs.length;
console.log(inputLenth);
```

**Reference**
[Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Cool! Good to know there is more than one way to solve my problem